# WebRTC on Localloopback

Tags: webrtc, gstreamer

I would like to ask about a problem with video transmission via WebRTC within the one PC. My system is configured as follows

**camera ---> python (GStreamer) ---> Browser**

When this PC is connected to LAN, the video transmission by WebRTC succeeds. (This LAN is not connected to the Internet.) The network configuration is as follows

**Router --- PC**

The network consists of only one router and one PC.

However, if this PC is disconnected from the LAN, the video transmission via WebRTC failed. Specifically, both the server and the client failed to generate ICE candidates. (The onicecandidate callback is not called)

What is the cause of this problem? Is WebRTC not able to make local loopbacks as route candidates? Also, I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC / ICE in the browser ignores the loopback address for candidate gathering because signaling it will not lead to a connection with a peer in all normal cases.

If gstreamer supports signaling a loopback candidate it might work (at least in Chrome, Firefox only has support for this behind a flag or so)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I found libnice library (that is used by GStreamer for create ICE candidate) omit loopback.
So I modify libnice and rebuild GStreamer, WebRTC streaming worked.
But I have a thing I can't understand. GStreamer side create ICE candidate now, but Browser side still not create ICE candidate, of cause I don't any care for Browser side. But why WebRTC connect success? I think both side must create ICE candidate, but my understanding is wrong?

Comment: The reason this works is that the browser binds to the "any" address and connects to the remote loopback candidate and the other side (in this case libnice) discovers this as a peer-reflexive candidate.